# SQL database instance cannot be set to SINGLE_USER

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make my database Single User Mode and I tried executing this:

`ALTER DATABASE [db] SET SINGLE_USER WITH NO_WAIT`

and it returned:

`Option 'SINGLE_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'.`

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  There are a lot of different SQL servers.

Comment: the "sql-server" tag relates to MSSQL server. The fact that he's trying to touch the master database confirm this

Comment: Is the AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC option off ?
Do you have ALTER DATABASE permission on the database ?

Comment: You're not trying to set the master database into single user mode are you?  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic886847-146-1.aspx